# How to get attributes from array without attributes functions

Tags: php, arrays, xml

I want to know how to read attributes from an array without using `attrubites()`. Below is a part of my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<offer file_format="IOF" version="1.0" generated="2017-12-27 11:04:38" >
<products currency="PLN">
    <product id="2055">
        <price gross="709" net="577"/>
    </product>
```

Below you have my code which reads all attributes. I want to remove `$product->attributes()->id` because it returns an array value which I need to "clean" with `json_decode(json_encode($id), TRUE);` and then `$xmlArray[0];` to read a value.

```
$xmlUrl = 'myfile.xml';
$xmlVar = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($xmlUrl));
foreach ($xmlVar AS $products) {
    foreach ($products AS $product) {
        $id = $product->attributes()->id;

        $xmlArray = json_decode(json_encode($id), TRUE);
        $withOutId = $xmlArray[0];
    }
}
```

I want to convert this array to string by moving

```
json_decode(json_encode($id), TRUE);
```

in the begin but I don't know how I can read attributes then. Thanks for help.

Kind regards

Comment: file_get_contents does not  return an array. You can use fopen() and fgets() loop to create an array

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
$id = $product->attributes()->id;
```

doesn't return an array, it returns a `SimpleXMLElement` object. There's no need to run it through `json_encode/decode`, you just need to cast it to a basic PHP type:

```
$id = (int) $product->attributes()->id;
var_dump($id); // int(2055)
```

Another slightly cleaner way to access attributes is to use array-style syntax:

```
$id = (int) $product['id'];
var_dump($id); // int(2055)
```